# Pull random word from list in txt file by char length

Tags: python

I have a task to pull a random word from text file (in same path) defined by user input.
File has single strings in each line:

```
Lilongwe
Male
Bamako
Valletta
Majuro
Nouakchott
Chisinau
Monaco
```

Struggling  with code:

```
import random

file = "file.txt"


def random_list(file):
    list_of_words = []
    with open(file) as words:
        for line in words:
            list_of_words.append(line.replace("\n", ""))
    return list_of_words


list_of_words = random_list(file)
# print(list_of_words)

user_input = input("1. up to 4 letters\n2. 5 -8 letters\n3. 9-16 letters\n--> ")

def diff_level():
    if user_input == "1":
        while len(list_of_words) > 4:
            pulled_word = random.choice(list_of_words)
            print(pulled_word)
            break
    elif user_input == "2":
        while len(list_of_words) > 8:
            pulled_word = random.choice(list_of_words)
            print(pulled_word)
            break
    elif user_input != "2" or "1":
        while len(list_of_words) > 16:
            pulled_word = random.choice(list_of_words)
            print(pulled_word)
            break

diff_level()
```

Function returns basically random word no matter char length.

Comment: There's a lot of problems here. It's unclear why you put your code into a function. You then loop until the length of the list of words no longer exceeds some value, but you don't change the length of the list. It appears from the prompt that you wanted to filter the list instead and pick a random word from it, but that's not happening anywhere. Reading the file happens with more code than is needed.

Comment: What do you want to and what is a problem?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Since you haven't clearly stated what problem you're trying to solve and what output you actually get, we're not really able to help you "fix" it.

Comment: @Grismar - it's a part of word game, hence def in code

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were after, perhaps it helps to understand a working example, but I think you would do well to examine your own code and try to figure out why you put in most of the lines, because it seems you're struggling with some of the basics.

```
import random

with open("file.txt") as f:
    words = f.readlines()

option = input("1. up to 4 letters\n2. 5-8 letters\n3. 9-16 letters\n--> ")

lower, upper = {'1': (1, 4), '2': (5, 8), '3': (9, 16)}[option]

result = random.choice([word for word in words if lower <= len(word) <= upper])
print(result)
```

Some feedback on your code:

- organising code in functions is a good idea, but don't write functions for the sake of writing functions; your second function just seems to be an if statement with needless break statements;
- don't write code for stuff that already exists; the first function basically does what a standard function can also do;
- don't repeat yourself; if you see bits of code that are very similar, it's often better to think of a way to write it in one go, since that reduces the odds of mistakes and often makes your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

First, your condition range is weird.

> above 4, above 8, above 16 ?

Second, your **len** function gets "list of words". which is:

```
[Lilongwe, Male, Bamako, Valletta, Majuro, Nouakchott, Chisinau, Monaco]
```

thus, always 8.

Third, if there's no word matching the length range in the list: Welcome to the infinite while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an optimal data structure (dictionary of lists) to solve this problem.

**Updated Code:**

```
import random

file = "file.txt"


def random_list(file):
    words = {'upto_4': [], 'upto_8': [], 'upto_16': []}
    with open(file) as words:
        for line in words:
            if len(words) <= 4:
                words['upto_4'].append(line.replace("\n", ""))
            elif len(words) <= 8:
                words['upto_8'].append(line.replace("\n", ""))
            elif len(words) <= 16:
                words['upto_16'].append(line.replace("\n", ""))
    return list_of_words


words = random_list(file)
# print(list_of_words)

user_input = input("1. up to 4 letters\n2. 5 -8 letters\n3. 9-16 letters\n--> ")

def diff_level():
    if user_input == "1":
        pulled_word = random.choice(words['upto_4'])
        print(pulled_word)
    elif user_input == "2":
        pulled_word = random.choice(words['upto_8'])
        print(pulled_word)
    elif user_input != "2" or "1":
        pulled_word = random.choice(words['upto_16'])
        print(pulled_word)

diff_level()
```